# __cdecl wrapping WinSock function as callback in plain C and call it

Tags: function, callback, winsock, stdcall, cdecl

Have prepared such function, where some WSA functions will be used as callback:

```
int StartWinSock(int (*WSAStartup)(WORD, LPWSADATA))
{

}
```

But when in other code, I'm trying to launch it:

```
StartWinSock(WSAStartup);
```

I'm getting an error:

> 'WSClient::StartWinSock' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int (__stdcall *)(WORD,LPWSADATA)' to 'int (__cdecl *)(WORD,LPWSADATA)'

Also, I don't know how to pass parameters correctly through callback function like WSAStartup() ( its parameters: WORD ( unsigned short number of version ) && LPWSADATA ( reference to WSAData ) ).

Comment: *"Also, I don't know how to pass parameters correctly..."* Ask one question at a time. Lumping multiple questions into one makes it very difficult to provide accurate and complete answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `__stdcall` calling convention on the function pointer type, which comes from the `WINAPI` macro.  The compiler is therefore assuming the default `__cdecl` calling convention for this pointer.  The two calling conventions are not compatible.

Consider creating this typedef:

```
typedef int WINAPI (*WSAStartupCallback)(WORD, LPWSADATA);
```

Then declare your function like this:

```
int StartWinSock(WSAStartupCallback wsaStartup)
{
}
```

You should then be able to call this function with the external `WSAStartup` pointer.